# Bloqueio de caracteres com exceção campo e-mail

Tags: javascript

Estou usando este codigo para bloqueio dos caracteres especiais, mas esta bloqueando também no campo do e-mail.
como resolvo? ou como permito @ . e _

```
$(function(){
 var regex = new RegExp('[^ 0-9a-zA-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b-]', 'g');
 // repare a flag "g" de global, para substituir todas as ocorrências
 $('input').bind('input', function(){
 $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regex, ''));
});
})
```

Comment: Você só precisa adicionar dentro dos colchetes:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você só precisa adicioná-los dentro dos colchetes:

```
var regex = new RegExp('[^ 0-9a-zA-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b-@_]', 'g');
```

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se entendi corretamente sua pergunta, mas em seu código você aplica a expressão a todos os inputs.

Uma alternativa é definir os inputs que deseja validar através de uma classe.

Obs.: o comando .bind() está obsoleto, utilize o .on()

> As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by
>   the .on() method for attaching event handlers

Exemplo:

```js
$(function(){
   var regex = new RegExp('[^ 0-9a-zA-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b-]', 'g');
   $(".validar").on('input', function(){
      $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regex, ''));
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
 <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="validar"    placeholder="Digite seu nome" />
</div>
<div>
 <input type="text" name="idade" id="idade" class="validar" placeholder="Digite sua idade" />
</div>
<div>
 <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail"/>
</div>
```